# While loop only display first row from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I know its a super basic question but I can't find an answer all day.
I'm trying to display all of my database rows in a table and my while loop only displays the first row.

I tried to change the condition of the while loop to "mysqli_fetch_array" and then not even the first row showed up.

```
echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>
        <th>Match_Id</th>
        <th>Home_Team</th> 
        <th>Away_Team</th>
        <th>Result</th>
        <th>season</th> 
        <th>notes</th>
        <th>Goals_Sum</th>
      </tr> ";


     $sql = "SELECT * FROM PremierLeague";
   `enter code here`  $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

 while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     echo "<tr>";
     $id = $row['id'];
     echo "<td>$id</td>";
     $Home = $row['Home'];
     echo "<td>$Home</td>";
     $Away = $row['Away'];
     echo "<td>$Away</td>";
     $result = $row['result'];
     echo "<td>$result</td>";
     $season = $row['season'];
     echo "<td>$season</td>";
     $notes = $row['notes'];
     echo "<td>$notes</td>";
     $home_goals= $row['home_goals'];
     $away_goals= $row['away_goals'];
     $GoalSum = $home_goals+$away_goals;
     echo "<td>$GoalSum</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
 }
  echo "</table>";
```

Expected result: table with all rows from database.
Actual result: only the first row from database

Comment: Why are you using a while loop in the first place? This is the kind of problem for loops were designed for.

Comment: Can you give an example how I can do this with a for loop?

Comment: your code have syntax error.did you paste it correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>
        <th>Match_Id</th>
        <th>Home_Team</th> 
        <th>Away_Team</th>
        <th>Result</th>
        <th>season</th> 
        <th>notes</th>
        <th>Goals_Sum</th>
      </tr> ";


     $sql = "SELECT * FROM PremierLeague";
  $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

 while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
          $Home = $row['Home'];
          $Away = $row['Away'];     
        $result = $row['result'];
       $season = $row['season'];
       $notes = $row['notes'];
     $home_goals= $row['home_goals'];
     $away_goals= $row['away_goals'];
     $GoalSum = $home_goals+$away_goals;



 echo $output.="<tr>
                 <td>$id</td>
                 <td>$Home</td>
                 <td>$Away</td>
                 <td>$result</td>
                 <td>$season</td>
                 <td>$notes</td>
                 <td>$GoalSum</td>
                </tr>";
 }
  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I did and it was a mistake, so I removed it. Sorry about this. However, I don't see in what your proposition is different from the OP one…

Comment: Copied your code, and still only one row is displayed.

Comment: Is the condition in the while loop ok?

Comment: remove SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC from while loop & try it.

Comment: didn't change anything

Comment: execute with print_r($row); after while loop

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample looks cleans at first sight but this still reminds me of two distinct possibilities :

- Your table only contains one row. It's silly but it must be checked first. Well, I supposed you did ;
- An extraneous semi-colon ";" forgotten after a `while()` condition:

```
    while($res=fetch(…));
    {
        display something…
    }
```

In this case, the loop will iterate until the end of your dataset, then the block in curly brackets (assumed to be orphan) will be entered, displaying what's remaining in the variables. But in this case, you should get the **last** row of your query, not the first one.

Comment: 1. My table contains more that one row. 2. For sure it displays the first row, so it's not the the semi-colon, even though I tried to add it and then no row showed up.